# Linking a eventdate to another value in a group by

Tags: mysql

I can currently trying to run this query to get the most recent event:

```
SELECT id, id2, MAX(event_date), numeric as numeric 
FROM table 
group by id, id2;
```

Basically the problem is you can have 2 numeric values per each event_date, my objective is to only be able to pick the highest value of these numerics.eg

Yet I don't seem to be able to do that in a single query. I've tried using a having clause(but that's too restrictive and removes valid values) assignment operators but am a bit stumped.There must be a simple way of doing this. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: you can replace `numeric as numeric` with `numeric`

Comment: for every `(id, id2)`, do you want the largest numeric, or the numeric which is in the same row as the largest event_date?

Comment: largest numeric which is in the same row as the largest event_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to get max of numeric field after selecting max of event_date, you need a sub query to get the max of numeric field.

```
SELECT id, id2, MAX(event_date),numeric_field
FROM event_table A
where numeric_field in 
(select max(numeric_field) from event_table 
   where A.id = id and A.id2 = id2 and A.event_date = event_date)
group by id, id2;
```

I have created a SQL fiddle to try out different examples. [SQLFiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b377/1/1)

Note: I have renamed "numeric" field to "numeric_field" in query